# programatically invoking Sass::Exec::SassConvert generates wrong syntax

Tags: ruby, sass

```
Sass::Exec::SassConvert.new(["{path_to_scss_file}.scss", "{path_to_css_file_to_generate}.css"]).process_result
```

When I run following command from inside a ruby script, the generated file contains "sass"-syntax instead of valid css
When I try to add a set_opts command to specify "-F scss -T css", just to be sure the convertor knows what to do, it throws an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `banner=' for ["-F scss -T css"]:Array
```

The goal is to compile scss files to css files from inside an ant build script.
Everything is working except for the wrong syntax issue.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: is ```banner=``` part of your application?

Comment: no, that is actually the first line of the set_opts method from the SassConvert class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the script to use `Sass::Engine` instead of `SassConvert`.

After looking through the code of the SassConvert class, the following fragment pointed me to the solution:

```
unless [:scss, :sass].include?(@options[:to])
    raise "Unknown format for sass-convert --to: #{name}"
end
```

It appears the SassConvert class only converts CSS files to .scss or .sass, not the other way around.

Also, the correct way to add option flags when calling `Sass::Exec::SassConvert`, is by doing the following:

```
sassConvert = Sass::Exec::SassConvert.new(["-F scss", "-T sass", "{path_to_from_file}", "{path_to_file_to_generate}"]
sassConvert.parse!
sassConvert.process_result
```